# fancy footer text plus page number

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm trying to add a page number at the bottom center. I want the text in the fancy footer to come up one line, so that the page number is not on the same line as the words.  Right now, the number is colliding with the words.  What's the best way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[A4paper,10pt,openany]{book}

%PACKAGES
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all headers and footers
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove rule between header and text
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}% header height adjust to remove warning

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{%
   \fancyhead{}%
   \fancyfoot[LE,LO]{very very  very very very very very very very very very very very verylong very long very long amount of text}%
}

\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\blindtext


\end{document}
```

Comment: Use short headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise the letters a bit using either `\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\parbox{\linewidth}{<text>}}`, or set it in a `p`-width `tabular`. Here is an approach using the latter, with an additional blank line (containing `\strut`) at the bottom of the `tabular`; you can also just use `\\[\normalbaselineskip]` instead of the `\strut`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all headers and footers
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove rule between header and text
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}% header height adjust to remove warning

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{%
  \fancyhead{}%
  \fancyfoot[LE,LO]{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}
    very very very very very very very very very very very very very verylong very 
      long very long amount of text \\
    \strut
  \end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document} 

\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: An alternative would be to place the page number as part of the "very long text."...

Comment: How would I move the text up one more line, so that the number is not on the same line as the text?

Comment: You probably should use `\begin{tabular}[b]{...`

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Thanks; forgot that.

Comment: @R.B.Jawad: I've updated my answer to use `\begin{tabular}[b]{..}`, which improves the layout and is probably more inline with what you want.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I may be trying to use the wrong package.  If I make that very long text 10 lines long, it runs off the page.  I was trying to get a behavior similar to the \footnote{sometext}.  If you put a long \footnote, it raises it up and leaves the page number at the same position.  I think it's probably a weird thing I'm asking.

Comment: @R.B.Jawad: Should the text flow from page 1 to 2? Or is page 1 completely separate from its contents relating to page 2?

Comment: No, it shouldn't flow over.  I have a bunch of data in the footer on each page, and I was trying to figure out a way to put the page number down there, too.  However, I think it looks better to move the page number to the top corner.  It's too confusing with all the other numbers to put it at the bottom.  I didn't mean to waste your time.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, this adds the text using everypage instead of fancyhdr, making the added text independent of the pagestyle.

```
\documentclass{book}
%PACKAGES
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{showframe}

\addtolength{\footskip}{\baselineskip}

\AddThispageHook{\ifodd\value{page}\let\margin=\oddsidemargin
  \else \let\margin=\evensidemargin
  \fi
  \rlap{\hskip\margin
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \normalbaselineskip-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-\footskip}%
    [0pt][0pt]{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}%
    {very very  very very very very very very very very very very very very
      long very long very long amount of text}}}}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{document} 

\blindtext

\end{document}
```