# Big copyright footnote on every page of my document

Tags: thesis, copyright

I am currently starting to write my internship thesis. The company where I am doing my internship wants a copyright (text of several lines) to appear at the bottom of each page of the report (except the cover page).

Would you have any idea how I could do this? I haven't found a solution that suits me on the forums.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may set the footer, possibly with `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: You can create a second footer using the approach in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533165/fancy-footer-text-plus-page-number/533278?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C30.7945#533278. but I would now use `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{...}` instead of the everypage package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573329/so-what-is-the-everypage-package-replacement?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C57.1432).

Comment: Either method suggested above will work. If you use the background method, be aware that if you do not leave enough room, it will interfere with the main text.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answers!

I am new to LaTeX and can't see how to implement what you are telling me. In addition, my school makes us use a template, and some of the features I tested did not work on an article with the template. I have access to the DTX file (source code of the template) so I could add the lines of code that you would tell me to add. 

Could you help me?